# What proguard is doing when -dontobfuscate -dontshrink -dontoptimize are used?

Tags: jar, spring-boot, proguard

I have a project that is using spring boot and when is build it generates a jar containing all dependencies jars.

I want to obfuscate this jar, but after obfuscation when I try to run the jar I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'lib/h2-1.4.185.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:378)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:355)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:45)
```

I tried to find what is the issue and for that I create a config file only with:

```
-injars MyJar-orig.jar
-outjars MyJar.jar

-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/jce.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar(java/**,javax/**)
-libraryjars '..\..\resources\proguard5.0\references\log4j-1.2.17.jar'

-dontobfuscate
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
```

I was expected to get the original jar, but I am getting a jar that is smaller and all the classes have different size (smaller in general).

What is proguard doing in this case?
Any idea how I can solve my issue?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  If so can you post your solution please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at the '-keepattributes' parameter. When using the Proguard GUI, under the 'Obfuscation' tab there is an option for this. Clicking this solved my problem which was similar/ the same as yours.

Comment: 1) It did not remove the problem for me, 2) it is not recommend look at their docs # Uncomment if you want to have more meaningful backtraces
# Useful for obfuscation debugging
# You absolutely must keep this commented out for production
 -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable